# Personal workbook isn't running macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting up a new computer and created a Personal workbook. The workbook has code that is called with a hotkey that makes buttons appear. I put the Personal workbook in my XLSTART folder.

I have two computers, both with the same code. One of them works and the other doesn't. I have WinMerge to compare the two, and they are the same.

There is a worksheet called "Sheet1" in my personal workbook that has "Button 1" and "Button 2."

The line that errors is:

```
Set pwb = Workbooks("Personal").Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

The error is

> Runtime error '9': Subscript out of range"

```vb
Sub make_buttons_appear_onhotkey()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pwb As Worksheet

Dim shape1 As Shape
Dim shape2 As Shape
Dim shape3 As Shape
Dim shape4 As Shape

Dim shapetop As Long
Dim shapeleft As Long
Dim shapeheight As Long
Dim shapewidth As Long

Dim shapetop2 As Long
Dim shapeleft2 As Long
Dim shapeheight2 As Long
Dim shapewidth2 As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Set pwb = Workbooks("Personal").Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set shape1 = pwb.Shapes("Button 1")
shapetop = shape1.Top
shapeleft = shape1.Left
shapeheight = shape1.Height
shapewidth = shape1.Width
shape1.Copy
ws.Paste
Set shape3 = ws.Shapes("Button 1")
shape3.Top = shapetop
shape3.Left = shapeleft
shape3.Height = shapeheight
shape3.Width = shapewidth

Set shape2 = pwb.Shapes("Button 2")
shapetop2 = shape2.Top
shapeleft2 = shape2.Left
shapeheight2 = shape2.Height
shapewidth2 = shape2.Width
shape2.Copy
ws.Paste
Set shape4 = ws.Shapes("Button 2")
shape4.Top = shapetop2
shape4.Left = shapeleft2
shape4.Height = shapeheight2
shape4.Width = shapewidth2

Application.OnKey "{ESC}", "make_buttons_disappear_onclick"

Range("A1").Select

End Sub

Sub make_buttons_disappear_onclick()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

ws.Shapes("Button 1").Delete
ws.Shapes("Button 2").Delete

Application.OnKey "{ESC}"

End Sub
```

Comment: Probably another assumption to get out of the way - is there any chance that macro security is interfering with the opening of the Personal workbook on the problem machine. I'm guessing not ... since you are saying its an open (and visible!) workbook. FWIW, I have once or twice gone to the trouble of completely rebuilding a seriously problematic workbook (using clean everything from scratch as much as possible).

Comment: Exactly *how* does it not work?  You’ve not told us the symptoms …

Comment: Have you tried *Set pwb = Workbooks("Personal.xlsb").Worksheets("Sheet1")*? It is related to *File Explorer > Options > View > Advanced Settings > Hide extensions for known file types*.

Comment: Tim- the error is "Runtime error 9: subscript out of range"

Comment: VBasic2008, yes I tried that too

Comment: VBasic2008 Well, it turns out that I did need to do that or else change the setting. This didn't completely solve my problem though- see my comment in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the Default file location in File->Options->Save. It should be
drive:\fullpath\XLStart and in the Trusted Location in Trust Center.
Subscript out of range in this case means that a file with the given name is
not found in the directories, where Excel look for.

Comment: Apparently I had it in the wrong XLSTART folder. I did a search for it and I guess I didn't wait for it to finish searching. It had a path with "Excel" in it. Never occurred to me that there would be more than one XLSTART folder. I also had to enable macros in the macro settings. Man I hate setting up a new computer. Anyway, thanks bro!